# Namespace extension fails to work on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, com, explorer

I have a NE plugin for explorer that has worked fine with XP, but fails to show anything in Win 7 (x64). During startup of plugin the `IShellFolder::CreateViewObject` is called with `riid={CAD9AE9F-56E2-40F1-AFB6-3813E320DCFD}` which is an interface IID I have not been able to determine what it is. Of course I then return `E_NOINTERFACE`, and that's it. No more calls to the method. Googling this unidentified IID seem to indicate an undocumented interface IID. How can I implement an undocumented interface? Frustrated. Ideas?

Comment: Did you rebuild your extension to target x64?

Comment: @Hans: Yes, it would be difficult for explorer to call my plugin if I hadn't... ;)

Comment: Responding E_NOINTERFACE to an undocumented IID is good manner, and certainly not the reason why your program doesn't work. IMHO you're chasing the wrong mouse.

Comment: @Simon: You might be right, I've been testing the ExplorerDataProvider example, and the CreateViewObject method is called first with the IID mentioned, THEN with others including IID_IShellView. In my case, I get only the first call. I have no idea what differs, yet.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the ExplorerDataProvider was only called ONCE with IID_IShellView. Subsequent debug sessions, even with logging off windows in between, does not call CreateViewObject with IID_IShellView anymore. Still the sample shows everything OK in explorer. This is pure Microsoft magic.

Comment: Could also be a threading model issue (for example of a similar behavior: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/20/77120.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the answer or not, but it seems that if Visual Studio is used to debug a 64 bit target, a VS debugging monitor is used as a proxy (since VS is a 32 bit appl), and it seems that there is a problem debugging the Namespace Extension via Windows Explorer UNLESS the debugger is ATTACHED to the explorer executable (i.e. Attach = No in debug settings makes it work as above)!!

So, when I use Attach=Yes to attach to explorer, I get ALL interface calls to `IShellFolder::CreateViewObject`. Go figure.

This took 3 days out of my life, thank you Microsoft.